# Get alpha channel from UIImage rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, alpha, cgcontext

Given a CGRect (`rect`) and a UIImage (`image`), how do you obtain the alpha values (only) of the image pixels in the rectangle?

The following code always returns 0 alpha, no matter the image or rectangle.

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             rect.size.width,
                                             rect.size.height,
                                             8,
                                             rect.size.width,
                                             NULL,
                                             kCGImageAlphaOnly);

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[image drawInRect:rect];
char *pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
NSUInteger pixelCount = rect.size.width * rect.size.height;
for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++)
{
    char pixel = pixels[i];
    CGFloat alpha = pixel / 255.0;
    NSLog(@"%f", alpha);
}
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: curious if you tried my recommendation below. Wondering if it solved the problem?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Nope.

Comment: I wonder if the colorspace matters when you are capturing a picture from the context. Have you tried creating a  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); and assigning it to the 6th argument (replacing NULL).

Comment: @Spectravideo328 According to this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1037/_index.html , the color space should be NULL.

Comment: Where is your image coming from and are you sure it has 1 bit only of non-zero alpha?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Yup. I managed to get this working using CGContextDrawImage instead of drawInRect:, as stated in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I have had issues getting CGBitmapContext working properly.  I wouldn't be surprised if there was an issue with `kCGImageAlphaOnly`.  You might do some sanity checking with some of the more 'mainstream' pixel formats like `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst`.

You might also try drawing the image using `CGImageDrawImage`:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                         rect.size.width,
                                         rect.size.height,
                                         8,
                                         rect.size.width,
                                         NULL,
                                         kCGImageAlphaOnly);

CGContextDrawImage( context, rect, image.CGImage);

//etc...

CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: I tried with CGContextDrawImage and kCGImageAlphaOnly works as advertised. I'd say I'm using drawInRect: incorrectly. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea.  Perhaps UIGraphic has an undocumented problem with kCGImageAlphaOnly pixel formats, or maybe calling UIGraphicsPopContext() before trying to harvest the data would work (just wild guesses). However, since you're doing everything else at the CG level, it seems unnecessary to jump up to the UIGraphics level to do your drawing.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 the code for getting only the alpha channel would looks like this:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func alphaData() -> [UInt8]? {
        let size = self.size
        var alphaData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(size.width) * Int(size.height))
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let context = CGContext(
            data: &alphaData,
            width: Int(size.width),
            height: Int(size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: Int(size.width),
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue
        );

        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        return alphaData
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add an extracted alpha data to another UIImage

Answer (score 0):

`pixelData[index + 3]` will be a value for Alpha. `pixelData[0-2]` are RGB respectively

CFDataRef theData;

```
    theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage));

    CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, theData);

    UInt8 *pixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(mutableData);

    int dataLength = CFDataGetLength(mutableData);

    for (int index = 0; index < dataLength; index += 4) {
       //code here for just alpha
       pixelData[index + 3]
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `kCGImageAlphaOnly` return just one byte, as indicated here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1037/_index.html ?

Comment: You can still manipulate the data or reset that pixel in the for statement. Ex. if I want to change the alpha from 1 to 255, multiply it by 255.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. You not using the input rectangle, and loading the whole image into memory.

Comment: my code uses an image, but I believe you can get the same RGBA sample from any view. [index + 0(0) -> 0(3)] gives you RGBA values in 0-3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with RGBA values is that they all have to be unsigned char. I am guessing this might have caused your problem since a signed char would stop at 127 and never attain the full 255 value if this image had an opacity of 1 - and possibly worse not being properly aligned (read).

Comment: Changing to unsigned char didn't change the result. That said, it should be unsigned char anyway so I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.. https://github.com/OgreSwamp/ObjFloodFill