# SwiftUI Path as contentShape, doesn't line up with Image

Tags: layout, swiftui, mask, hittest

**TL;DR**: I'm using a `Path` to specify the hit area for an `Image`. But I don't know how to adjust the `Path` coordinates to match the layout that SwiftUI decides on... or if I even need to do so.

**Runtime**

My (test) app looks like this, `Image` borders (*not* frames) colored for clarity:

[image: screenshot]

What I *want* is for taps in the opaque orange to be handled by that `Image`. Taps outside the opaque orange — even if within the bounds of the orange image — should "fall through" either to the green image or the gray background. But no. (The purple outline shows where the path is, according to itself; see code below).

**Details**

Here's the intrinsic (in pixels) layout of the images:

[image: orange square with transparent boundary]

The path around the opaque part is trivially seen to be

```
[(200, 200), (600, 200), (600, 600), (200, 600)]
```

How do these coordinates and the `Image` coordinates relate?

**Code**

```
extension CGPoint {
    typealias Tuple = (x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat)
    init(tuple t: Tuple) {
        self.init(x: t.x, y: t.y)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var points = [(200, 200), (600, 200), (600, 600), (200, 600)]
        .map(CGPoint.init(tuple:))
        // .map { p in p.shifted(dx:-64, dy:-10)}  // Didn't seem to help.

    var path : Path {
        var result = Path()
        result.move(to: points.first!)
        result.addLines(points)
        result.closeSubpath()
        return result
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("gray")       // Just so we record all touches.
            .resizable()
            .frame(maxWidth : .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("background")
            }

            Image("square_green")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .border(Color.green, width: 4)
            .offset(x: 64, y:10)    // So the two Images don't overlap completely.
            .onTapGesture {
                print("green")
            }

            Image("square_orange")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .contentShape(path)        // Magic should happen here.
            .border(Color.orange, width: 4)
            .offset(x: -64, y:-10)
            // .contentShape(path)     // Didn't work here either.
            .onTapGesture {
                 print("orange")
            }

            path.stroke(Color.purple)  // Origin at absolute (200,200) as expected.

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asperi was correct, and it dawned on me when I read [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/paths-vs-shapes-in-swiftui) and grasped the (single) requirement of `Shape` — a path(**in rect: CGRect**) -> Path method. The `rect` parameter tells you all you need to know about the local coordinate system: namely, its size.

My working code now looks like this.

**Helpers**

```
extension CGPoint {
    func scaled(xFactor:CGFloat, yFactor:CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: x * xFactor, y: y * yFactor)
    }

    typealias SelfMap = (CGPoint) -> CGPoint
    static func scale(_ designSize: CGSize, into displaySize: CGSize) -> SelfMap {{
        $0.scaled(
            xFactor: displaySize.width  / designSize.width,
            yFactor: displaySize.height / designSize.height
        )
    }}

    typealias Tuple = (x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat)
    init(tuple t: Tuple) {
        self.init(x: t.x, y: t.y)
    }
}
```

**Drawing the Path in proper context**

```
// This is just the ad-hoc solution. 
// You will want to parameterize the designSize and points.

let designSize = CGSize(width:800, height:800)
let opaqueBorder = [(200, 200), (600, 200), (600, 600), (200, 600)]

// To find boundary of real-life images, see Python code below.

struct Mask : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let points = opaqueBorder
            .map(CGPoint.init(tuple:))

            // *** Here we use the context *** (rect.size)
            .map(CGPoint.scale(designSize, into:rect.size))

        var result = Path()
        result.move(to: points.first!)
        result.addLines(points)
        result.closeSubpath()
        return result
    }
}
```

**Using the Mask**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("gray")           // Just so we record all touches.
            .resizable()
            .frame(
                maxWidth : .infinity,
                maxHeight: .infinity
            )
            .onTapGesture {
                    print("background")
            }

            // Adding mask here left as exercise.
            Image("square_green")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .border(Color.green, width: 4)
            .offset(x: 64, y:10)    // So the two Images don't overlap completely.
            .onTapGesture {
                print("green")
            }

            Image("square_orange")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .border(Color.orange, width: 4)

           // Sanity check shows the Mask outline.
            .overlay(Mask().stroke(Color.purple))

            // *** Actual working Mask ***
            .contentShape(Mask())

            .offset(x: -64, y:-10)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("orange")
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Getting the Outline**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# From https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/f2kv1/question_on_tracing_an_image_in_python_with_pil

import sys
import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
import pygame

# Find simple border.

fname   = sys.argv[1]
image   = pygame.image.load(fname)
bitmask = pygame.mask.from_surface(image) 
comp    = bitmask.connected_component() 
outline = comp.outline(48)

print("name:  ", fname)
print("size:  ", image.get_rect().size)
print("points:", outline)

# Sanity check.
# From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-polygon-method

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImagePath
import math

box = ImagePath.Path(outline).getbbox()
bsize = list(map(int, map(math.ceil, box[2:])))

im = Image.new("RGB", bsize, "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(outline, fill="#e0c0ff", outline="purple")

im.show()      # That this works is amazing.
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It has been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

1) `.offset` only shifts content, but position of view in view hierarchy layout is not changed, so use instead `.position`;

2) shape for `contentShape` should be constructed in view coordinate space

Comment: Yes and yes. Especially point 2). I left the `offset` in my posted solution. Have to leave some work for my successors.